# Ajax Object - 12030 Loop Fix?

Tags: javascript

Here are 3 methods which handle my ajax calls.

I loop until pass b.c. I've had problems with the Ajax Object working as expected.  This is noted [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_23421667.html)

```
/**
 *    Ajax
 */

var Ajax = ( function () 
{
    var Ajax = function (element) 
    {
        this.object = this.create();
    };
    Ajax.prototype.create = function() 
    {
        var request;
        try
        {
            request = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch( error )
        {
            try 
            {
                request = new window.ActiveXObject( "Msxml2.XMLHTTP" );
            }
            catch( error )
            {
                try
                {
                    request = new window.ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
                }
                catch( error )
                {
                    request = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return request;
    };
    Ajax.prototype.use = function( param, ajax_func )
    {
        var GATEWAY = 'class.ControlEntry.php';  
        var self = this;
        this.object.open( "POST", GATEWAY, true );
        this.object.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
        this.object.setRequestHeader( "Content-length", param.length );
        this.object.setRequestHeader( "Connection", "close" );
        this.object.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if( this.readyState === 4 )
            {
                if( this.status === 200 )
                {
                    ajax_func( this.responseText );
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    self.invoke( param, ajax_func );
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
        this.object.send( param );
        return true;
    };
    Ajax.prototype.invoke = function( param, ajax_func )
    {
        var state = false,
            count = 1;
        while( state === false && count <= 5 )
        {
            if( count !== 1 )
            {
                alert( 'Ajax Object Use Failed | Try Again ');
            }
            state = this.use( param, ajax_func );
            count++;
        }
        return state;
    };
    return Ajax;
} () );
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: First question would be how do I not loop my ajax...has anyone else had an issue with the 12030 error code...showing up about 10% of the time...

Comment: It seems to me that if the AJAX request has a genuine failure (maybe the path doesn't exist, or there's a network issue, or some kind of error on the server); then you'll be stuck in an endless loop.  Maybe you should limit the number of times that you call ajaxRepeat.  Also, I don't much like the names of your functions; it's not very clear what each one does.

Comment: This code doesn't work, it does not belong here ([faq](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq)). This is troubleshooting that belongs on SO.

Comment: 'issue with the 12030 error code...showing up about 10% of the time' - This is softawre, working 90% of the time doesn't cut it.

Comment: Yes, your code looks much nicer now.  Probably the next step is to work out where the 12030 errors are coming from.  Is there any particular URL that's making them happen?  Or does it happen for lots of different URLs?

Comment: @Paul - please direct you comments to Microsoft.

Comment: @David - I posted the link stating that this is a known issue with IE above.

Answer (score 1):

This is the real bad practice.

1. The Ajax is Asynchronous, you never know how the response will back.
2. Javascript is the single thread language, so that means in one time period just can run one function. in your repeatUseAjax function, you try to loop send ajax. the result will be you will send 5 times ajax call every time when the ajax response failure.And you will never know when the response suceess. what about first failure other success? what about always failure?loop forever?

Comment: I do not try and loop "send ajax".  If ajax responds with a fail ( it has completed )..then I make another request.